# how to create a hierarchy on the page object model classes?

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

This might be a very strange question, but I am not even sure how to title this question. I am quite new to C# and Selenium. I have done some coding on it and I'm quite comfortable creating a (quitemessy) test that runs how I want to. I would like to organize my tests a bit better.

I will use this as an example to what I want to achieve:

On a login page lets say I have a button "Log In" and that button opens a page that let's me put my credentials "Username" and "Password".

Lets say i would like to program it like this: have the landing page with the login with all the elements of that page, and one only for the elements of the login page.

And the test would be something like this:

```
LandingPage.Login.Click();
LandingPage.Login.Username("username");
LandingPage.Login.Password("password";
LandingPage.Login.LoginBtn.Click();
```

and then after the Log In is completed i could have something like:

```
Database. (everything in the database page). (actions or areas i can navigate to)
```

There would be some hierarchy on this classes. Username belongs to login, login belongs to LandingPage, and so on.
I have seen this type of coding being used. I'm starting to create a "page object model" for my test and would like to separate it so then i can use the way I showed above. The "`LandinPage.cs`" would have the login link as well as other elements and the "`Login.cs`" would have the username field and the password and the login button, along side other elements not relevant now.

I also understand that this is not really for unit testing but more integration testing.

My question is, is there a name for this kind of formatting? I am struggling to find such so I can start my studying there.

Answer (score 0):

I put this together quickly so it may not be 100% correct technically, but this gives you some idea of how you can pass between a Landing Page and a LogIn Page

LandingPage.cs

```
public class LandingPage
{

    IWebDriver driver;
    readonly By loginBtn = By.Id("some_id");

    public LandingPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    
    // below is the important piece, the clickLogIn method returns an instance of the LoginPage where you can continue on
    public LoginPage clickLogIn()
    {
        driver.FindElement(loginBtn).Click();
        return new LoginPage(driver);
    }
}
```

LoginPage.cs

```
public class LoginPage
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    readonly By userName = By.Id("passwordID");
    readonly By passWord = By.Id("userID");

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        driver.FindElement(userName).SendKeys("user");
        driver.FindElement(passWord).SendKeys("password");
    }
}
```

Then your test would look something like this:

```
var landing = new LandingPage(driver);
var loginPage = landing.clickLogIn();
loginPage.Login();
```

As mentioned don't take the details literally, but the part that is commented in `LandingPage.cs` is the important piece on how you can return new Page Objects from a specific page

Answer (score 0):

I've read a lot but never come across exactly what you are talking about. Instead, I would suggest that you read up on Page Object Model as you mentioned and stick to it. It is and has been the industry standard for years.

Here are a couple links to get you started from the Selenium docs.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

This is written by Martin Fowler. He's pretty much the inventor of the modern page object.
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html

With just about anything, you have to be careful with blogs, SO answers, etc. on page object model. Not everyone is doing it correctly. These links above are good though and I'm sure you can find more. To give you a quick example of how to implement them in your case,

LandingPage.cs

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace SeleniumSandbox.PageObject
{
    public class LandingPage
    {
        IWebDriver Driver;

        // this actually isn't a Login button, it's a "Form Authentication" link but for demo purposes...
        private readonly By _loginButtonLocator = By.CssSelector("a[href='/login']");

        public LandingPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.Driver = driver;
        }

        public void ClickLogin()
        {
            Driver.FindElement(_loginButtonLocator).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

LoginPage.cs

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace SeleniumSandbox.PageObject
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        IWebDriver Driver;

        private readonly By _loginButtonLocator = By.CssSelector("button");
        private readonly By _passwordLocator = By.Id("password");
        private readonly By _usernameLocator = By.Id("username");

        public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.Driver = driver;
        }

        public void Login(string username, string password)
        {
            Driver.FindElement(_usernameLocator).SendKeys(username);
            Driver.FindElement(_passwordLocator).SendKeys(password);
            Driver.FindElement(_loginButtonLocator).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

SampleTest.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using SeleniumSandbox.PageObject;

namespace SeleniumSandbox.Tests
{
    public class SampleTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void LoginTest()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            string url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/";
            driver.Url = url;

            string username = "tomsmith";
            string password = "SuperSecretPassword!";

            new LandingPage(driver).ClickLogin();

            new LoginPage(driver).Login(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a sample page site created by one of the Selenium contributors, Dave Haeffner, and is a working example. You'll need to pull in the following NuGet packages.

DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
NUnit
NUnit3TestAdapter (if you want to run the test from the Test Explorer in Visual Studio... highly recommended for at least debugging tests, etc.)
Selenium.Support
Selenium.WebDriver
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver (or whatever browser you want to use)

Comment: This is a super simple, no frills version of a test and page objects. There are many, many things you can add using NUnit, creating a BagePage class to hold common FindElement functions, etc. that will make this much easier to use, create new tests, make tests run more consistently, run in parallel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [Page Object Model](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/) pattern is the name. And there are three crucial concepts to the Page Object Model design pattern:

1. Expose **operations** as methods that encapsulate a user interaction.
2. Use **Data Hiding** to hide the internals, like locators and web elements.
3. Public methods on your page object that cause a transition from one page to another should **return another Page Object** representing the other page.

The `LandingPage` class should have a method that navigates to the login page, and this method should return a LoginPage object:

```
LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
LoginPage loginPage = landingPage.NavigateToLoginPage();
```

Then the `LoginPage` should have a method that logs the user in, and returns the page object for whichever page the user should go to next:

```
landingPage = loginPage.LogIn("username", "password");
```

Then make your assertions on the `LandingPage` object.

The full flow could look like:

```
var landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
var loginPage = landingPage.NavigateToLoginPage();

landingPage = loginPage.LogIn("username", "password");
```

You could also use method chaining to tighten up your code:

```
var landingPage = new LandingPage(driver).NavigateToLoginPage()
                                         .LogIn("username", "password");
```

Having the login page be a "sub page" of the landing page is the wrong abstraction. They are separate pages. An action on one page leads the user to another page, which is represented by the return types on `NavigateToLoginPage()` and `LogIn(string, string)`.

Comment: #3 is not a requirement for POM. There are many arguments for and against it. I personally don't like it because it forces you to write more methods than you really need to (in error cases, etc. where you need to return a different page object depending on state), doesn't provide much value when you do use it, and is prone to abuse where your entire test is a single chained command which makes it unreadable and really difficult to debug.

Comment: @JeffC: Without #3 you lose a powerful abstraction with this design pattern.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't always use chained methods for everything in your test, but that doesn't mean it isn't useful from time to time.

Comment: And when a user interaction has multiple results, either expose different methods for each result, or create an object that contains all possible page models, but only one of them has an object. The rest could be null.

Comment: 1) I don't believe it's as powerful as you claim. I'm aware how it works and I've tried it. I think it's oversold. If you like it and find it useful, great. 2) Why have the ability to chain and not chain? But if you chain, the tests become hard to read and hard to debug. 3) Option 1 requires a bunch of extra methods be written for error cases, etc. which, unless you are careful, makes things less DRY. Option 2 sounds pretty terrible... then you have a bunch of `if then` code in your tests to figure out what path to take next which adds to the complexity of the tests and make them hard to read.